# Why is RAII and garbage collection mutually exclusive?

Tags: language-agnostic, garbage-collection, raii

While I think I understand the gist of the problem (i.e. a good GC tracks **objects**, not **scope**), I don't know enough about the subject to convince others.

Can you give me an explanation on why there are no garbage-collected languages with deterministic destructors?

Comment: -1 The question is wrong. There are garbage collected languages with deterministic destructors, e.g. `IDisposable` on .NET provides deterministic destruction for C#, VB.NET and F#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are NOT mutually exclusive. Feel free to use C++ with libgc (Boehm-Reiser-Detlefs collector). You can still use RAII, smart pointers, and manual deletion, but with the GC running you can also just "forget" to delete some objects.

@Andy's answer regarding resources being disposed too late misses the important point: it isn't the delay releasing resources which is crucial semantically, but rather the order of release.

The reason GC tends not to order release well is that it would require a topological sort on ordering requirements (dependencies) and that's an expensive algorithm.

Nevertheless Ocaml GC has an interesting facility where you can attach a finaliser to an object. If the object becomes unreachable the finaliser is run, however the object is not deleted (because the finaliser could make it reachable again: in that case you can even attach another finaliser). These finalisers can provide some control over ordering.

Comment: The order of release can be important. But an undefined delay to release, and possible complete failure to release, can also be important. It's not either-or, it's both-and.

Comment: An undefined delay to release may indeed be important, that includes releasing memory! Performance matters. But it isn't relevant semantically. Complete failure to release, however, does matter, but it can't happen if the GC is run at the point of termination. For some resources such as file handles on Unix one tends not to run the GC on termination because the OS will release the resources anyhow. The general advice using a GC is do NOT use RAII for critical resources, release under program control. However it's not clear what that means with lazy evaluation eg in Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Determinism), after noting that tracing garbage collectors are the most common type:

> Tracing garbage collection is not
>   deterministic. An object which becomes
>   eligible for garbage collection will
>   usually be cleaned up eventually, but
>   there is no guarantee when (or even
>   if) that will happen.

Therefore, relying on RAII could lead to the resource being disposed of too late.

As a result, for example, Java has a guideline to "avoid finalizers" (Item 6 in "Effective Java" by Josua Bloch). "Nothing time-critical should ever be done in a finalizer."

Comment: FWIW the Wikipedia page on garbage collection is mostly wrong, including that section.

Comment: @JonHarrop - Any specific criticisms of this answer are welcomed.

Comment: It's clear that the action of a simple GC algorithm is completely deterministic in a single threaded application. It may or may not be hard to predict, but my system at least has an explicit collect() call which runs the GC and will run finalisers. The determinism is only lost in multi-threaded applications, which may have bounded or unbounded non-determinism anyhow (depending on the system and application), so it's not clear that even in that case a GC makes things any worse than they are already.

Comment: @Yttrill: Exactly but I think the underlying problem is that none of the people who use the word "determinism" in the context of garbage collection understand what that word actually means.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector can't run all the time (refcounting gets closer, but generally doesn't count as garbage collection), so it doesn't even try. It's plain impractical. Therefore, there is an inevitable delay between an object becoming unreachable (e.g. because the only reference goes out of scope) and the GC collecting it, possibly firing a finalizer. This delay is not deterministic... unless (and then, deterministic destruction in the strictest sense of the word is possible, although still impractical) force the GC into a deterministic schedule - but this gets pretty close to "GC running all the time", which is still incredibly impractical.

So GC and deterministic cleanup are mutually exclusive because the GC does all the cleanup and it cannot afford do be deterministic but must rely on maximizing its efficiency.